# How can i remove videos from later for individual users?

Tags: django

`views.py`
here in views.py i have tried to make logic for remove any song from watch later but, i am not able to
build logic for it.Basically dont know how to bring watch_id(primary key) of my watch later model.

```
def deletewatchlater(request):
    if request.method=="POSt":
        user=request.user
        video_id=request.POST['video_id']
        # watch_id=request.POST['watch_id'] 
        wat=Watchlater(user=user,video_id=video_id)
        wat.delete()
        messages.success(request,"Song delete from watch later")
    return render(request,'watchlater.html')

def watchlater(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        user=request.user
        video_id=request.POST['video_id']

        watch=Watchlater.objects.filter(user=user)
        for i in watch:
            if video_id==i.video_id:
                messages.success(request,"Song is already added")
                break
        else:
            wl=Watchlater(user=user,video_id=video_id)
            wl.save()
            messages.success(request,"Song added to watch later")
        return redirect(f"/index/subpage/{video_id}")
    wl=Watchlater.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    ids=[]
    for i in wl:
        ids.append(i.video_id)
    
    preserved=Case(*[When(pk=pk,then=pos) for pos,pk in enumerate(ids)])
    song=Allmusic.objects.filter(sno__in=ids).order_by(preserved)
    
    return render(request,'watchlater.html',{'song':song})
```

`urls.py`
I have made post request for it when user clicks button remove from watch later than it will send details of user and song_id and watchlater id

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('postComment',views.postComment,name="postComment"),
     

    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('index/',views.index,name='index'),
    path('indexmovie/',views.indexmovie,name='indexmovie'),
    path('index/subpage/<str:sno>',views.subpage,name='subpage'),


    path('about/',views.about,name='about'),
    path('contact/',views.contact,name='contact'),
   
    #User Login Logout Signup
    path('signup',views.handleSignup,name='handleSignup'),
    path('login',views.handleLogin,name='handleLogin'),
    path('logout',views.handleLogout,name='handleLogout'),

    path('search/',views.search,name='search'),

    #User Saved 
    path('index/watchlater',views.watchlater,name='watchlater'),
    path('index/history',views.history,name='history'),
    path('index/likedsongs',views.likedsongs,name='likedsongs'),


    path('index/deletewatchlater',views.deletewatchlater,name='deletewatchlater'),

]
```

`watchlater.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} watch Later {% endblock %}
{% block css %}
<style>

</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1 style="text-align:center;padding-top: 5%; "> WATCH LATER</h1>

{% if song|length < 1 %}
<h1 style="text-align:center;padding-top: 5%; "> You have not added anything in watch later</h1>
{% endif %}



<div class="container">
  {% for i in song %}
  <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 940px; padding-top: 3%;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">Song Name:{{i.name}}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">Artist Name:{{i.author}}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">Movie Name:{{i.movie}}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">Category:{{i.category}}</h5>


          <a href="/index/subpage/{{i.sno}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Listen Song</button></a>

          <form action="/index/deletewatchlater" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="video_id" value="{{i.sno}}">
            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="watch_id" value="{{i.watch_id}}"> -->
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Remove from Listen Later</button>
        </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Allmusic(models.Model):
    sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    author=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    description=models.TextField(default="")
    movie=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    category=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    subcategory=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default="")
    musicfile=models.FileField(upload_to='music_file', default="")
    length=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  

class Watchlater(models.Model):
    watch_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video_id=models.CharField(max_length=100000,default="")
    

class BlogComment(models.Model):
    sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment=models.TextField()
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post=models.ForeignKey(Allmusic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent=models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(default=now)


class History(models.Model):
    history_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    music_id=models.CharField(max_length=100000,default="")


class Likedsongs(models.Model):
    like_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video_id=models.CharField(max_length=100000,default="")
```

Comment: could you please share your models also

Comment: sir, updated my code take a look it.

Answer (score 0):

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Allmusic(models.Model):
    sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    author=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    description=models.TextField(default="")
    movie=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    category=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    subcategory=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default="")
    musicfile=models.FileField(upload_to='music_file', default="")
    length=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  

class Watchlater(models.Model):
    watch_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_id=models.ForeignKey(Allmusic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

class BlogComment(models.Model):
    sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment=models.TextField()
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post=models.ForeignKey(Allmusic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent=models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(default=now)


class History(models.Model):
    history_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_id=models.ForeignKey(Allmusic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Likedsongs(models.Model):
    like_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_id=models.ForeignKey(Allmusic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**watchlater.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} watch Later {% endblock %}
{% block css %}
<style>

</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1 style="text-align:center;padding-top: 5%; "> WATCH LATER</h1>

{% if song|length < 1 %}
<h1 style="text-align:center;padding-top: 5%; "> You have not added anything in watch later</h1>
{% endif %}



<div class="container">
  {% for i in song %}
  <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 940px; padding-top: 3%;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src='/media/{{i.image}}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">Song Name:{{i.name}}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">Artist Name:{{i.author}}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">Movie Name:{{i.movie}}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title" style="color: green; font-weight: 550;">Category:{{i.category}}</h5>


          <a href="/index/subpage/{{i.sno}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Listen Song</button></a>

          <form action="/index/deletewatchlater" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="song_id" value="{{i.sno}}">
            
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Remove from Listen Later</button>
        </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def deletewatchlater(request):
    if request.method=="POSt":
        user=request.user
        song_id=request.POST['song_id']
        wat=Watchlater.objects.get(song_id=song_id, user=user)
        wat.delete()
        messages.success(request,"Song delete from watch later")
    
    return render(request,'watchlater.html')
```

OK I changed your models, view and template.
Changes are these

1. Creating a foreign key(song_id) in Watchlater, History, Likedsongs models with relationship between AllSongs.
2. In template we pass {{i.sno}} which is equal to song_id in Watchlater, History, Likedsongs models.
3. In Your view we get this song_id and filter Watchlater model with these fields(song_id and user) and delete.

Comment: sir,i am doing in this way it shows that watch_id is set to none

Comment: in your template you are sending     <input type="hidden" name="video_id" value="{{i.sno}}">   <!-- <input type="hidden" name="watch_id" value="{{i.watch_id}}"> -->, songs primary key, you are not sending watch_id, watch_id is not in songs.

Comment: yes sir watch_id is not in songs thats why i dont know logic for it that how should i pass watch_id with it.can you suggest anything for it.

Comment: is video_id in watchlater model equals to sno in Allmusic?

Comment: No, video_id is basically made to send with the hidden input tag which shows the I'd of each song. Same thing is used for comments, watchlater, history just for song id and in input I put value ={{i.sno}} where i is varible and sno is from models of Allmusic

Comment: May be this will work, how can I use watch_id in watchlater in Allmusic model so, that when I post request for delete watch later I can pass watch_id in value so I can delete it from specfic user.

Comment: @DhruvilShah my friend I updated my answer. As I said previously you have to create a relationship between watchlater and allsongs model. Here we create it with song_id.

Comment: how to deal with default value which asks to give default value while adding the field.Will I have to delete the whole content in database?

Comment: For example,,  Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
>>> 'default'

Comment: You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'song_id' to history without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: My friend as I said before, type 1 enter, then again type 1 and hit.

Comment: Did same thing before but still it shows the same -You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'song_id' to history without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows). Please select a fix: 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column) 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py